# underline the text within a textbox

Tags: css

I would like to know how i can underline my text within a textbox (CSS solution if possible)?

```
<textarea>
MyText
</textarea>
```

Now the Text: MyText should be underlined.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite a simple bit of CSS:

```
textarea {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This will literally underline every single bit of text in the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `border-bottom:1px solid black;` to underline the entire textbox, OR

do `text-decoration:underline;` to underline only the text that's inside the box. Since you are using `textarea`, I think this is the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
textarea { text-decoration:underline; }
```

If it is not "taking", you could force the style:

```
textarea { text-decoration:underline!important; }
```

Or add more specificity:

```
body form textarea { text-decoration:underline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use CSS, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Texarea css example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #t {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="t">your text here</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```